# No Operating System Found following Ubuntu Server 20.10

Tags: boot, system-installation

I have tried 16 ways to Sunday to install Ubuntu Server on this machine I have. Its an IBM 8 gigs of ram blah blah should work machine.

- installing from USB stick and DVD Rom with the exact same problem.
- The BIOS is set to UEFI (tried all configs on this)
- I have tried to manually select the boot device and also let it run through in automatic mode, no dice

The end result is this, install appears to be fine, I tell it to use the entire disk, all the settings throughout the install are default I change NOTHING.

At the end, when it tells me to reboot, I remove the stick or Disc and hit enter. There is then an error about "unable to eject the CD ROM Media or USB media" I ignore it remove the install media and hit enter.

The machine comes up, finds an ip address and and bang "no operating system found"

Coincidentally, every bloody tutorial on the internet shows installing using a VM via Windows, which by the way works fine on my other machine running windows 10 and Virtual Box.

I do not know much about Linux.

Is it installed? Yes it is, because when I tried yet again to install using Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 version it confirmed that another version of Ubuntu is residing on the hard drive???

What I do not need is for someone to tell me to check the BIOS again. I have tried it in every possible configuration and nothing is working. So just leave that be please. I have read all the other posts on this board related to what I am struggling with.

What I believe is going on is the MBR or bootloader or whatever boots the OS is not pointing to the correct mount point or something to that effect.

So I need some step by step tutorial on how to modify "GRUB?" or whatever is telling this machine where to boot from on the hard drive. If you can do that for me, I will buy you a beer.

// Begin Edit

Additional:
As per request, I ran the boot repair linked to me below.

Results:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/KSvvdNnZfV/

After rebooting the machine following the boot repair, same issue Error 1962 No OS found. Press any key to repeat boot sequence.

As you can see from the paste bin there is actually two versions installed on the drive, it is still in the configuration because after the failed attempt with Server 20.10 I tried the desktop install to see if it would get this working. Which it did not.

I am hoping you guru's can figure this out from the paste bin info

Thanks again for helping!

// End Edit

Please help!

- Chris

Comment: How many disks are installed in this machine? If more than one, is it possible that grub is installed on the wrong disk? During installation you can select which disk to put the MBR on. Maybe it defaulted to a disk which isn't the boot disk? External USB drives attached?

Comment: 1 disk - 500 Gigs. Not trying to dual boot or anything I just want a Linux machine to learn with.

Comment: Sorry, also nothing connected via usb except keyboard and mouse.

Comment: "At the end, when it tells me to reboot, I remove the stick or Disc and hit enter. There is then an error about "unable to eject the CD ROM Media or USB media" I ignore it remove the install media and hit enter."  Usually *after you hit restart* it asks you to remove the installation media. Are you waiting for that prompt, or are you removing it before you restart?

Comment: Hi OM, sorry I typed that out in frustration the process is > hit enter to reboot > asks to remove media > remove media > reboot proceeds > fail

Comment: Typically, we use [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#A2nd_option_:_install_Boot-Repair_in_Ubuntu) to fix problems like this. Boot up a live session using the Ubuntu installer USB or DVD (select: "try Ubuntu without installing") and from the Live Session, use the "2nd option" listed on the tutorial I gave the link for (run the commands to install boot-repair and then run the repair). If that doesn't work, please edit your question and provide the information and any errors (verbatim please).

Comment: Also, this is just a wild guess but you might want to try the reboot without removing the device. After the reboot, shut down normally, then remove the device and then power back on.

Comment: mchid, I corrected myself with respect to the "reboot" process in the comments, I have run the boot repair as per your advice results have been edited into the post above along with the paste bin info. Still not working.